# How to properly shield a < 5v Circuit from EMI from a 220v motor?

Tags: motor, snubber, emi-filtering

I've designed the following circuit:

[image: circuit]

It may be trivial to most people but I did not know that the EMI generated by the motor and coil would interfere with my circuit. After some research I stumbled uppon the concept of Snubbers. So I upgraded the circuit as such:

[image: circuit2]

I've upgraded the code aswell, coded a small logic to check if the button was really pressed 50ms after the initial trigger.

Things improved a bit, but sometimes if I turn the motor on and off many times in a row (like 10 times), it may get the circuit to a corrupt state, not responding to button presses, but still working, updating the LCD, etc.

Any ideias on how to improve the design and get rid of that EMI (I'm assuming it's EMI) ?

Comment: What does your layout look like? Decoupling?

Comment: You got reflections, overshoot, ringing, etc... I think you don't need those pull-up / pull-down thing. You need `termination diode`

Answer (score 1):

Flyback diode on the contactor coil is usually a good idea. Also you've drawn the power supply upside down.

Your drive setup is a bit weird: what is the whole R1/C1/R2 setup for?

EMI can be either conducted or radiated. Normally you'd investigate to determine which, but this requires at the very least a scope. So you'll have to experiment with:

- put the device in a grounded metal box (not possible in your case if you're using the PCB antenna radio)
- attach ferrite chokes to all pairs of external leads

Comment: The contactor is triggered by the motion of the machine, I'm just using the NO contact from the contactor, so the resistors (R1 and R2) are the pull-ups and the capacitor (C1) would be some sort of decoupling capacitor (not sure if implemented right).

Comment: Ah I see, it's an input not a relay coil. In which case it looks like an OK debounce circuit (not decoupling). The other possible problem is power drop-outs caused by the high starting current of the motor. But at this point you need to put an osciliscope on the power rails, or add lots more bulk capacitance there.